# My ajax doesn't work in live()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, live

I have a link in my page and I wrote in it's `onclick()` event to show me a div that contain a date input text named "datepicker0" and also I have a div id ="bContent" below this input text.

Now I wrote below script and I want to apply date Filter on my data in "bContent",
but it doesn't work! Appreciate any help please...

```
$('#datepicker0').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).datepicker().datepicker('show');
    true;
 })
 $('#datepicker0').live('change', function() {
    ShowMathesByDateFilter($(this).val());
 })
```

and `ShowMathesByDateFilter()` Function is :

```
function ShowMathesByDateFilter(Fdate)
{

  if (Fdate=="")
  {
  $("#bContent").html('<div class="bContent" dir="rtl"> no result are fond! </div>');
      return;
  }
  else
  {
      $.ajax({
          url:'/includes/GetMtch.php',
          data:"Fdate="+Fdate,
          success: function(data){
              //alert(data);    // this is work 
              $("#bContent").html(data);   //but this line doesn't work.
          }
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you initializing dateppicker inside focus handler? Suggest you make a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: data picker is work properly in my example. the problem is about after selecting new date in data picker, that filtered data with new date dont show in $("#bContent").html(data);

Comment: what example?  WHere's the demo that replicates the issue?

Comment: sorry i cant work with "jsfiddle.net" . wich part of my question unclear? i think ajax cant find   div #content that generated live to run this code: $('#content').html(data)

Comment: I would use `onSelect` of datepicker to get the date  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect Really have no idea whay you can't work with fiddle...everyoe else on this site does

Answer (score 1):

what version of jquery are you using?
live is depreciated as of jquery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/live/

try using 'on' instead of live:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

I agree with  charlietfl's comment. There seems to be an issue with this line:

```
$(this).datepicker().datepicker('show');
```

Comment: No, that not my Problem.  see here please : http://jsfiddle.net/bkardan/vTscW/39/

Comment: i found solution! thank you both of you charlietfl's and user1122614 !